How to Get visionOS Headset Position and Rotation for Object Translation in Swift?
I'm working on a visionOS app where I need to track the headset's position and rotation to translate an object based on the user's head movements. Specifically, I want to allow the user to move a circle anchored to a plane using head rotation and position. After the user performs a pinch gesture, the circle should disappear, and a new object should be instantiated at the new location.
However, I am struggling to find any code examples or documentation that support this functionality. Every time I come across code that uses ARView, Xcode informs me that visionOS does not support it.
Here's a brief outline of what I am trying to achieve:
Track the visionOS headset's position and rotation.
Use this data to move a circle anchored to a plane.
On pinch gesture, remove the circle and instantiate a new object at the specified location.
Does anyone have any experience with this or know how to accomplish it? Any code snippets or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.
What I've tried:
Looked for examples using ARView, but they are not supported in visionOS.
Searched for visionOS-specific documentation, but haven't found any relevant examples.

If you want to achieve the same placement experience as the JigSpace application, you first need to get the position of the ground. This can be done by using the following code:
let floorAnchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal, classification: .floor)
content.add(floorAnchor)

Then, you can retrieve the floor height using:
let floorHeight = floorAnchor.position(relativeTo: nil).y

Next, you need to obtain the position of the user's head:
let arKitSession = ARKitSession()
let worldInfo = WorldTrackingProvider()
try await arKitSession([worldSession,cameraSession])
guard let device: DeviceAnchor = worldInfo.queryDeviceAnchor(atTimestamp: CACurrentMediaTime()) else {
    return
}
let transform: simd_float4x4 = device.originFromAnchorTransform

Then, you need to get the direction the user is facing (which is the -z direction of the head). After that, you perform a hitTest:
let origin = SIMD3<Float>(transform.columns.3.x, transform.columns.3.y, transform.columns.3.z)
let direction = -SIMD3<Float>(transform.columns.2.x, transform.columns.2.y, transform.columns.2.z)
entity.scene?.raycast(origin: origin, direction: direction)

Finally, you'll obtain the position where you should place the placement indicator on the ground. You might want the user to tap the indicator to confirm the placement. You can add a SwiftUI button as an attachment to the indicator (this is how the JigSpace application does it). Alternatively, you can directly add a CollisionComponent and InputTargetComponent to the entire indicator, and then use SpatialTapGesture().targetedToAnyEntity().onEnded on the RealityView to achieve the same functionality. However, I recommend using a SwiftUI button as an attachment because it allows for better accessibility.

Yes, as you have found, ARView is not supported in visionOS. The Apple article Bringing your ARKit app to visionOS outlines some approaches for moving to RealityView.
See How can a Model be anchored above the user's Head in visionOS? for a discussion of head tracking.
The head-tracking experience you're describing is not something seen in any of the first-party or third-party applications I've tried. The interactions are generally based on gaze tracking, not head tracking.

You could see the JigSpace application that let the user postion a circle before positoing a model, and this circle will move with your head move then after pinching it instantiate the model

Nice! That's a slick approach!
